# Thread Yield method simulation using Sleep

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am trying to understand threading concepts in .Net.
I am unable to use Yield() method. I want the control to go to a parallel thread when i becomes divisible by 10.

Please help.

Below is my sample code:

```
class ThreadTest
{
    //Index i is declared as static so that both the threads have only one copy
    static int i;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(WriteY);          
        i = 0;

        //Start thread Y    
        t.Start();                              
        //Do something on the main thread.
        for (; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (i % 10 == 0)
            {
                //Simulate Yield() function
                Thread.Sleep(0);
                Console.WriteLine("The X thread");
            }
            Console.Write(i + ":X ");
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void WriteY()
    {
        for (; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (i % 10 == 0)
            {
                //Simulate Yield() function
                Thread.Sleep(0);
                Console.WriteLine("The Y thread");
            }
            Console.Write(i + ":Y ");
        }
    }
}
```

I get the compile time error:

> System.Threading.Thread does not contain a definition for 'Yield'

**Answered by Tudor.** This method will only work on .Net 4.0 and upwards.

Ideally I would want one thread to start and want each thread to execute for 10 incremented of i each. With my current method, I either get all 'X' or all 'Y'.

**Edit:**
With inputs from Tudor and TheHe - I have been able to get alternate X and Y. The crux of the problem was usage of lock object. But the output of this code is not predictable.

Comment: You say "does not work" - well, what did you *expect* to happen, and how are you checking to see what *actually* happens? threading is all-kinds-of-complex, and a `Thread.Yield` is an *incredibly* subtle thing to try to observe. I've done a large amount of threading work, and that is *not* a method that I ever need to use. Take a step back: can you explain what is it you are trying to do here?

Comment: `Yield` is a .NET 4.0+ method. Are you running that version?

Comment: @Tudor, No. I am using VS 2008 and .Net 3.5. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: With your edit, @Tudor is entirely correct - you are simply targeting the wrong framework version. Update to 4.0 or 4.5; however! I don't think this method is going to do what *you* think it is going to do.

Comment: In .NET versions lower than 4.0 you can somewhat emulate `Yield` with `Thread.Sleep(0)` if you really want, but in any case, the code above won't really work.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I have put in my entire code and explained what I am trying to simulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.Yield` will simply enable the scheduler to select a different thread that is ready to run:

> Causes the calling thread to yield execution to another thread that is
>   ready to run on the current processor. The operating system selects
>   the thread to yield to.

If other threads in your application are also waiting on that lock, you can yield all you want, they won't get a chance to run.

Btw, `Yield` is a .NET 4.0+ method. Make sure you're not targeting an earlier version.

**Edit**: IMO, to do what you want you should use events:

```
class Test
{
    //Index i is declared as static so that both the threads have only one copy
    static int i;

    static AutoResetEvent parentEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);
    static AutoResetEvent childEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(WriteY);

        i = 0;

        //Start thread Y
        t.Start();
        // Print X on the main thread
        parentEvent.WaitOne();
        while (i < 100)
        {                
            if (i % 10 == 0)
            {
                childEvent.Set();
                parentEvent.WaitOne();
            }
            Console.Write(i + ":Y ");
            i++;
        }
        t.Join();
    }

    static void WriteY()
    {
        childEvent.WaitOne();
        while (i < 100)
        {
            if (i % 10 == 0)
            {
                parentEvent.Set();
                childEvent.WaitOne();
            }
            Console.Write(i + ":X ");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. I have updated my code block. Can you please let me know what is wrong with my simulation of Yield using Sleep?

Comment: This code works awesome! It generated the same output for the 5 runs I did. Let me dig into this code now! Thanks so much!

Comment: Re the `AutoResetEvent` implementation; you can do this more simply with `Monitor`.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: You're right in fact, but I've always had a weakness for events. :D

Comment: @Tudor it is worth overcoming that - the *events* come from the OS, IIRC, and involve more overhead. `Monitor` is handled entirely inside the CLR, so doesn't involve going via interop to the OS.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: You're right about this and indeed they are slower, but I've always been of the opinion that when signal performance starts to matter (whether you're using events or monitors) it means you're calling them too ofter so it's time to switch to spin locks anyway.

Comment: @Tudor indeed, that is a valid point too. I guess where you have a weakness for *events*, I have a weakness for *`Monitor`*. Either will get the job done, which is the important thing.

Comment: @MarcGravell: In the end I did get an excellent implementation of my requirement using two different methods! How awesome is that? Three cheers SO!

Answer (score 2):

Forget `Thread.Yield`; that is unrelated to what you are trying to do. Ultimately, you have a `lock`, which uses `Monitor` to synchronize access. Inside the `lock`, your thread exclusively has access. What you need to do is *relinquish* the lock temporarily; the way you do that is with `Monitor.Wait`. However, if you `Wait`, you also end up in the "waiting" queue rather than the "ready" queue, so in order to make sure that each thread gets attention, we also need to `Pulse`, both before the `Wait`, and also at the end (to make sure both threads get chance to exit). Here we go:

```
using System.Threading;
using System;
class ThreadTest
{
    //Index i is declared as static so that both the threads have only one copy
    static int i;

    //The lock object
    static readonly object locker = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(WriteY);

        i = 0;

        //Start thread Y
        t.Start();
        lock (locker)
        {
            // Print X on the main thread
            for (; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (i % 10 == 0)
                {
                    Monitor.PulseAll(locker); // move any "waiting" threads to the "ready" queue
                    Monitor.Wait(locker); // relinquish the lock, and wait for a pulse
                    Console.WriteLine("The X thread");
                }
                Console.Write(i + ":X ");
            }
            Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void WriteY()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            for (; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (i % 10 == 0)
                {
                    Monitor.PulseAll(locker); // move any "waiting" threads to the "ready" queue
                    Monitor.Wait(locker); // relinquish the lock, and wait for a pulse
                    Console.WriteLine("The Y thread");
                }
                Console.Write(i + ":Y ");
            }
            Monitor.PulseAll(locker); // move any "waiting" threads to the "ready" queue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution work good! It provides a perfect alternation between X and Y. But it also prints a last line: `100X`. But this is not supposed to happen. Why do you think it is happening?

Comment: I got it. Moved the `Console.Write(i + ":X ");` to the beginning of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

from my point of view, you're locking "locker" in current thread and want to yield the current task to an other thread...
the lock is held by the first thread all the time -- it can't work?!

you have to manually lock the objects if you want to use multiple threads...

Comment: I have updated the question. I get the compile time error with or without lock.

Comment: so basically, if there is a lock, then, yield would not have any effect. Is that what you mean?

Comment: worse:
yield wants to change the thread, but the lock is held on the other thread concurrently...